# Appcelerator Titanium developing iOS native module - having more than one module inside the package

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-modules

If I create a new module project than the templates comes with a default named convention class that inherits from TiModule.

I would like my module to encapsulate more than one module inside it, so I've created another class that inherits TiModule with the name or MyNewModuls.m

Everything compiles and built, but how can I call methods I've created on that module from javascript code? When I require my module, only methods from the original module file that inherits TiModule exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add multiple module subclasses in side a module package. Please check the Titanium Module documentation. In that the above scenario is clearly mentioned a module cannot have multiple module classes.